# Multiple call from same javascript function with ajax, object in parameters not the same between the function body and the ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've got a strange result when I called my javascript method with ajax. When the user click on an arrow, it load the data, I don't want the user to be stuck so I let him change when he want. And when the data come back from the server, I want to load the data at the good object in my collection.

html like that ( a little more complex than that but hard to paste and I think it's enough to understand) :

```
  <a href='#' data-bind='click:LoadExactResult'>Next</a>
```

js:

```
 function LoadExactResult(dateObj) {
    //method body
    (function(dateObj) {
        var payload = {
            searchCriteriaParam: "",
        };

        console.log(moment() + " - Calling Exact Date: " + dateObj().Date());
        dateObj().IsAllFlightLoading(true);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'bla/bla',
            data: payload,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(moment() + " - Exact Date Success: " + dateObj().Date());
                // ajax body.
            }
        });
    })(dateObj);
}
```

But the data always come back for the last loaded object... Here is the console log.

> ```
> 1410377364469 - Calling Exact Date: Mon Jan 05 2015 22:00:00 GMT-0500 (Est) 
> 1410377365234 - Calling Exact Date: Sun Jan 04 2015 21:10:00 GMT-0500 (Est) 
> 1410377365539 - Calling Exact Date: Sat Jan 03 2015 20:40:00 GMT-0500 (Est) 
> 1410377367559 - Exact Date Success: Sat Jan 03 2015 20:40:00 GMT-0500 (Est) 
> 1410377370488 - Exact Date Success: Sat Jan 03 2015 20:40:00 GMT-0500 (Est) 
> 1410377375648 - Exact Date Success: Sat Jan 03 2015 20:40:00 GMT-0500 (Est)
> ```

Comment: Hard to guess what's going on without seeing the calls to LoadExactResult(). It would appear you're calling it repeatedly with the same object, albeit with different values each time. When the various `ajax` calls return, they're printing the current value of the (same) object they were called with.

Comment: Ok was thinking it was something related to js .. I have a meeting, I'll post more info after.

Comment: Arrays and objects are passed by reference in javascript.  You're not getting a val, you're getting a reference for dateobj that if changed anywhere is changed everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the fact that `dateObj` was an observable from knockout and each time I was calling `dateObj()`. It was recalculating the value. I had to pass not a knockout observable to the function `LoadExactResult`, but a real object

```
function LoadExactResult(dateObj) {
    //method body
        var payload = {
            searchCriteriaParam: "",
        };

        console.log(moment() + " - Calling Exact Date: " + dateObj.Date());
        dateObj.IsAllFlightLoading(true);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'bla/bla',
            data: payload,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(moment() + " - Exact Date Success: " + dateObj.Date());
                // ajax body.
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and objects are passed by reference in javascript. You're not getting a val, you're getting a reference for dateobj that if changed anywhere is changed everywhere. We need to "break" the reference
by modifying the parameter being passed into your self executing function.

```
function LoadExactResult(dateObj) {
  //method body
  (function(dateObj) {
      var payload = {
          searchCriteriaParam: "",
      };

      console.log(moment() + " - Calling Exact Date: " + dateObj().Date());
      dateObj().IsAllFlightLoading(true);
      $.ajax({
          url: 'bla/bla',
          data: payload,
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
              console.log(moment() + " - Exact Date Success: " + dateObj().Date());
              // ajax body.
          }
      });
  })($.extend(true, {}, dateObj));
}
```

Comment: You should include the explanation of your comment with this answer. Answers that contain just code are not good, as it won't be obvious why you changed `dateObj` to `$.extend(true, {}, dateObj)`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer sorry for the late response. The problem was not that, it was related to the fact that dateObj was an observable from knockout and each time I was calling `dateObj()`. It was recalculating the value. I had to pass not a knockout observable to the function `LoadExactResult`, but a real object